# How to secure wardrobe to wall if 1.25" gap exists between wall and wardrobe

Tags: drywall, walls, drill, furniture

How do a secure a wardrobe to a wall if there is a roughly 1.25" gap between the wall and the wardrobe due to the molding on the wall? I'd prefer to not have a screw visibly poking out the back of the wardrobe and going into the wall because it positioned where it will be visible often. Are there any tricks I can employ to avoid the eyesore? Thanks!

Comment: Is this a permanent wardrobe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like the [Hangman Anti-Tip kits](http://hangmanproducts.com/products/furniture-anti-tip-kit?variant=233501262).  You can locate the anchors in the middle of the wardrobe so that the hardware isn't easily visible.  You would need to hit a stud to really get holding power.

Editing to add that while that would mean cutting a hole through the back panel, this is IKEA furniture, so the back panel is really just cardboard.  The anchors for the anti-tip install to the underside of the top, so if this is the route you try, be sure the screws you are using won't poke through the top!

Comment: Wow! Didn't know something like this existed! The top is thick enough so the screws won't poke through. I'm going with this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How is this solution different from a screw showing at the middle of the wardrobe?

Comment: isherwood, It's not different from a screw showing in the middle of the wardrobe. It is better than one screw at each end of the wardrobe. You'd really have to look behind the wardrobe to see in the middle. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I'd fasten a decorative/coordinating rail to the upper back of the wardrobe, or to the wall in that position, such that it appears to be a component of the wardrobe. Screw through the wardrobe back and the block into the wall. Its design depends on the design of the cabinet.

Comment: What does a coordinating rail look like? I'm a bit of a DIY noob.

Comment: I have no idea. Post a photo and I'll take a crack at it.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/bVvv5

Comment: It is IKEA furniture. The doors are very heavy and the wardrobe leans forward when the doors open. The red circle areas are the designated holes to secure the wardrobe to the wall. The green circle indicates where the screws will come through. It is right next to the bed so if a screw were to come through it would be highly visible. Thanks for your help!